# Como chamar uma “Stored Procedure” oracle c#

Tags: sql, .net, stored-procedures, oracle11g

Tenho a seguinte *procedure* no meu banco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando chamar minha *store procedure* no *.net* desta forma:

```
        public int CountEvent(int resourceId, int eventCounterDefinitionId, DateTime startDate, DateTime stopDate)
    {         
        int ret = 0;
        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[MyConnectionStrings.Default].ConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("ServerVersion: {0} \nDataSource: {1} \nHostName: {2}",
                    conn.ServerVersion, conn.DataSource, conn.HostName);

                OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand("PRODUCTION.COUNT_EVENT", conn);
                OracleParameter paramiter1 = new OracleParameter();
                com.Parameters.Add("@P_RESOURCEID", resourceId);
                com.Parameters.Add("@P_EVENTCOUNTERDEFINITIONID",eventCounterDefinitionId);
                com.Parameters.Add("@P_SHIFT_START", startDate);
                com.Parameters.Add("@P_SHIFT_END", stopDate);
                com.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.ExecuteReader();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                    
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }            
        return ret;
    }
```

No entanto, ao executar meu código, dá a mensagem de erro:

> Número incorreto de tipos de argumentos na chamada para
>   `'COUNT_EVENT'`

Alguém poderia me ajudar no porquê os parâmetros estão errados?

Comment: Proxima verz tente nao postar imagens e sem os trechos de codigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua procedure possui uma variavel de saida (out) , que deve ser declarada na sua chamada no c# também.

**Consumindo uma variável de saída**

```
ora_cmd.Parameters.Add("Lc_Exito", OracleDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

ora_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

var returno = ora_cmd.Parameters["Lc_Exito"].value
```

Assim o seu código deve funcionar.

**Cursor**

Notei também que o out da sua consulta é um cursor do oracle, um tipo mais complicado de trabalhar. O Codigo para consumi-lo seria algo assim:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("REC_CUR",OracleType.Cursor).Direction=ParameterDirection.Output;
con.Open();  
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

E você pegará ele assim:

```
cmd.Parameters["REC_CUR"].value
```

Comment: tentei adaptar o código, mas mesmo assim não funcionou.

Comment: Mesmo erro? posta como ficou o codigo alterado

Comment: postei o código nas resposta, adicionei apenas a variável de saída

Comment: Editei minah resposta, reparei que você está utilizando um cursos no out da store

Comment: Cara muito obrigado pela ajuda e pelo tempo dedicado, funcionou, o problema realmente era o parâmetro de saída!!

Comment: BOAAAAAA!!! TAMO JUNTO!  :)

Comment: E lembresse que todos os parâmetros tem que ser chamados, e do tipo cursos são mais difíceis de lidar. Bom dia, bom trabalho.